Prior year shapefiles of U.S. Electric Service Territories
a new question here based on this original post. Wondering if anyone who has been in search of this dataset, the current version from HIFLD provided in the linked post, has found any repositories of historical versions? I am looking for annual shapefiles starting from 2015. I don't know about the annual frequency, but I know that previous, deprecated, versions of this dataset existed. However neither HIFLD (the source for the EIA Energy Atlas version) nor S&P Capital IQ Pro (the current home of SNL Energy which maintains a comparable dataset) seem to keep prior versions--I reached out to both and was told they only have the most recent update.
Does anyone know of a source that would maintain and preserve these territory shapefiles? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
